# angularJS focus in bootstrap modal when it is opened when page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my app (yes i know that this is a little bit to bad) in controller have such code:

```
  $scope.changePasswordModal = function() {
    angular.element('#password-change').modal('show');
  };
```

this code appear so:

```
  if(angular.isDefined($routeParams.chgkey)){
    $scope.changePasswordModal();
  }
```

and i have such view:

```
<div class="modal custom" id="new-password-remember" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newPasswordRemember" aria-hidden="true" modal-center modal-auto-focus modal-auto-focus-type="1" modal-auto-focus-action="rememberpwd" data-backdrop="static">
....
```

i also have some other modal forms on this view: when i click to open modal - all is ok: focus is displayed. But when i open page and it is opened in controller via actions i see that it has focus, but why this focus is not displayed?

directive:

```
.directive('modalAutoFocus', ['$timeout', '$window', function ($timeout, $window){
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


        if (attrs.id == 'new-password-change'){
          element.find('.on-focus')[0].focus();
        }

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          element.find('.on-focus')[0].focus();
        });
    }
  }
  }]);
```

i didn't understand what is bad... why focus is not displayed? what i do wrong?

thank you

Comment: your element with the directive has the id new-user  instead of new-password-change  is this like you want it? is your directive also on a element with id new-password-change ?

Comment: @micha yes all is ok, just my mistake, i updated question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and that code fixed it:

```
$timeout(function(){
    element.find('.on-focus')[0].focus();
}, 0);
```

Comment: how to do with my directive?

Comment: you just change `element.find('.on-focus')[0].focus();` by the code above

Comment: `if (attrs.id == 'new-password-change'){
          element.find('.on-focus')[0].focus();
        }

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          element.find('.on-focus')[0].focus();
        });` i have two...

Comment: change both, you'll have two `$timeout(function(){
    element.find('.on-focus')[0].focus();
}, 0);`